# How to highlight rows which have same data in jQuery dataTables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using jQuery dataTables, but I want to change background color of row (`<tr>`) which have same company names but only two colors randomly (like gray and dark gray) as I have try to shown in images also. I have tried many things but somehow results are not accordingly to requirements. Anyone who know how to do it?

[image]

Image link here: http://i.cubeupload.com/hDM7AD.jpg

Comment: You will be able to use `fnRowCallback` for this. You will need to check the current row data against the previous row's data and apply a css class accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Done it by making Custom J query method :D